# Find implicit depending on implicit

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have an implicit value, that is depending on another implicit. I want to import the first implicit, when the second is in scope:

```
trait B
trait A

implicit def provideAnA(implicit b:B) = {
    implicit val a = new A{}
}

def myMeth(implicit a:A) = 42

{
    implicit val implB = new B{}
    // i would like to be able to pass this through compiler
    myMeth()    
}
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Besides the solution to your problem, could you please explain, why there is monad in the title, while your question does not include any monads?

Comment: @drexin my bad, I changed the question during writing, now edited. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition of `provideAnA` you create an implicit variable. This variable is not in scope of `myMeth` and is also unnecessary. Just return the value from `provideAnA` and it should work. So your `provideAnA` method should look like this:

```
implicit def provideAnA(implicit b:B) = new A{}
```

And also you have to remove the parentheses from the call to `myMeth`, because otherwise the compiler tries to call it without parameters and does not find an impl for that.